# TypeScript — Record or mapped type with optional never value

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I am building a type helper which merges an interface/object-type with a record where the record value-argument should be of type optional never. This util is meant to be used as a shorthand so you won't have to type out `key?: never` for every property.

Here's how far I've gotten.

```
type WithOptionalNever<T, Keys extends string> = T &
  Partial<Record<Keys, never>>

interface PropsWithout extends WithOptionalNever<Props, "ipsum" | "dolor"> {
  lorem: false
}
```

Which results in the following type:

```
lorem: false;
ipsum: never;
dolor: never;
```

That's to be expected. My train of thought was to then wrap the record in Partial, but that does not provide the desired result:

```
lorem: false;
ipsum?: undefined;
dolor?: undefined;
```

I've tried to achieve the same with mapped types, but it seems to result in the same behaviour as `Partial<Record<Keys, Never>>`.

Thoughts?

EDIT:

I've been asked to clarify how I'd like to proceed here, and it seems like what I'm asking for isn't intended behaviour nor does it hinder what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's a trivial example. I though `key?: never` would disallow passing of `lorem` prop unless `more` was explicitly set to true. I guess my question is then, is There a way to completely disallow passing of a property based on the absence/value of another?

```
interface Props {
  lorem: string
  more?: boolean
}

interface PropsWith extends Props {
  more: true
  ipsum: string
}

interface PropsWithOut extends Props {
  more?: false
  ipsum?: never
}

export default function Lorem(props: PropsWith | PropsWithOut) {
  return <></>
}

function Test() {
  return (
    <> 
      // I misunderstood and though ?: never would deny the passing of prop
      <Lorem lorem="fndjsk" ipsum={undefined} />
      <Lorem lorem="fndjsk" more={true} ipsum="hfjdsk" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (what's `Props`?) Are you saying that you want `{foo?: never}` instead of `{foo?: undefined}`?  If so, uh, [those are the same type](https://tsplay.dev/NBJnVN).  Unless you turn on [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), but I don't see you mentioning that anywhere.  Anyway, if that is what you're asking about (or even if it isn't) please [edit] the question so it's obvious.  How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Thought `?: never` would disallow passing prop, but seems I've misunderstood as undefined is till allowed. I guess this really isn't a problem then but I've updated the question asking if completely disallowing prop based on the absence/value of another.

Comment: Regardless of the "the absence/value of another" property, the closest you can get to "completely disallowing prop" is to do `?: never`.  If you turn on `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`, this will even disallow setting the value to `undefined` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3xbqW) (although you will still *read* `undefined` from that prop, since that's what JS does for missing props).   Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?